# Error while getting GCM token in client side

Tags: android, android-intentservice

package nath.prem.com.premgcmproject;

import android.content.Intent;

import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;

/** * Created by prem on 22/7/16. */ public class GCMTokenRefreshListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

//If the token is changed registering the device again @Override public void onTokenRefresh() { Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMRegistrationIntentService.class); startService(intent); } }

***Error while getting GCM token in client side***

FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)

at

com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)

**this is the error I am getting while getting gcm token**

public class GCMRegistrationIntentService extends IntentService { //Constants for success and errors public static final String REGISTRATION_SUCCESS = "RegistrationSuccess"; public static final String REGISTRATION_ERROR = "RegistrationError"; //Class constructor public GCMRegistrationIntentService() { super(""); } @Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { //Registering gcm to the device registerGCM(); } private void registerGCM() { //Registration complete intent initially null Intent registrationComplete = null; //Register token is also null //we will get the token on successfull registration String token = null; SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); try { //Creating an instanceid InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this); // // //Getting the token from the instance id token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null); //Displaying the token in the log so that we can copy it to send push notification //You can also extend the app by storing the token in to your server Log.w("GCMRegIntentService", "token:" + token); //on registration complete creating intent with success registrationComplete = new Intent(REGISTRATION_SUCCESS); //Putting the token to the intent // registrationComplete.putExtra("token", token); } catch (Exception e) { //If any error occurred Log.w("GCMRegIntentService", "Registration error"); registrationComplete = new Intent(REGISTRATION_ERROR); } //Sending the broadcast that registration is completed LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete); } }

**this is the java code of that class**

**this is my menifest file in the project......But I cannot see any of the logs in RegistrationIntentService:**

Comment: Please edit and format your code. check this http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

Add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'` dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
 private void registerToGCM() {
        new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.gcm_register_message));
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String registryId = null;
                try {
                    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    registryId = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("MAINACIVITY", "gcm register Error " + ex.toString());
                }
                return registryId;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String registeredId) {
                super.onPostExecute(registeredId);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                // perform action here
            }
        }.execute("");
    }
```